# Running an Arduino without the computer

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having trouble getting my Arduino Uno to run my code when I disconnect it from my computer.

I have a 9V battery to power it and it is turning on, however, it is not doing anything at all. What can I do to make it run the code when it is using the battery and not connected to the computer?

Comment: You should probably give some indication in the question on how you know it is behaving differently between battery power and usb power.  Also given that 9v are not particularly good batteries beyond their ability to produce 9v, you may want to say what else you have connected to the board.

Comment: If you use a 9V block battery, recycle it and buy better batteries. You could use a series of AA batteries

Comment: how do you know that the arduino is doing nothing?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the schematics? What is the code?

Comment: What components do you have in your project? Specifically, what are you connecting to the 5V line?

Comment: I have four DC motors connected to the Arduino. They each have a basic circuit with one transistor, resistor, and a diode for each. As of right now the objective is just to get the motors to run while its not connected to the computer. They run perfectly when connected to the computer but when I try to connect the battery so that it doesn't have to be connected to the computer, which it need to be able to be, the Arduino is on but nothing is happening. Do you have any better batteries that you recommend over the 9V?

Comment: To get a useful answer on a power source, you'd need to say more about the motors themselves.  You may find it instructive to put a voltmeter on the 5V line and alternately the VIN pin (or battery directly) and watch what is happening to their voltages when you attempt to operate the motors.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fresh 9V battery, or better, a proper power supply or some AA batteries in series, just to make sure the power supply isn't the problem.

BTW on some Arduinos (though probably not yours) it often pays off to check if there is a `while (!Serial);` or some such in the code. If there is, it is blocking code execution until the USB is connected and the serial monitor is opened.

Comment: A battery a day keeps the environment decay.

Comment: "For testing only". I never use primary cells myself.

Comment: while (!Serial); would have no effect on an UNO.

Comment: @timemage: People with different Arduinos will also read this Q&A without looking at the tag, so I thought it would be a good idea to include it.

Comment: @ocrdu: I was looking at more as UNO having been in the question, the while loop is thing is a more of a rabbit hole.  I suppose you could mark it as "for some boards this is also a problem."  I don't have really strong feeling about it really.  In case you're wondering, I didn't vote down your answer.

Comment: @ocrdu, Heh, I'd had a follow on this and saw your change come in.  I'm going to upvote this just to cancel out the -1 that, in my opinion, should not have been there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

And Arduino should run the last program installed to it when you apply power to the barrel connector. IT powers up, does a reset, and begins executing the sketch that's installed.

As others have mentioned, the small rectangular 9V batteries have very low current output and total power storage. You will run a fresh 9V battery down to nothing in a short time with just an Arduino, and with other components also drawing power it will happen even faster. I suggest getting a ≥ 1 amp 7V - 9V DC transformer and plugging that into the barrel connector.

You need to tell us what components you are using in your project and their current requirements.

If you are just running a "bare" arduino and very little else then you should get like 24 hours out of a fresh 9V battery, as mentioned by @ocrdu

Comment: All pins together can't source more than 150mA. Why should he use a 1000mA power supply?

Comment: @Duncan-C: Could be it, but power consumption is not THAT bad; 500mAh will run some Arduinos that aren't doing too much for about 24 hours.

Comment: I did find some that are 9V 1200mA batteries would these suffice?

Comment: You mean 1200 mAh? (that stands for milliamp-hours. It tells you the total power storage capability of the battery. A 1200 mAh battery can put out 1200 milliamps for an hour. (Or 120 milliamps for 10 hours. You just multiply current by time).